# Hybris : Synchronization cron job for web content catalog is not working

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud, wcm

I have created synchronization cronjob for for my sites content catalog, but is is not working as it should have to.

For staged content catalog site is working ok in cmscockpit.

for apparel-uk, when i change something in staged catalog, after cronjob run it reflects in online catalog, but in my new site it is not working.

When i start cronjob, it shows successful completion, when i check for online catalog of content it is not as it should.

Product catalog cron jobs working ok.

Answer (score 0):

Cronjob for content catalog synchronization should have associated CMS types. 
Please go to apparelContentCatalog Synchronization and check associated job in it, all types allocated to this job should be in your own content catalog synchronization job.